# Windows Internet Explorer 11 Update error - sfc /scannow fail

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-update, sfc

Since the last few days I am having problems with IE. IE starts for 1 second and immediately closes (1st Issue), furthermore IE11 Windows Update fails with code 9C48 (2nd issue)

To fix this issue I have searched all over the net and applied all the proposed solutions, including many FixIt, Deactivate/Reactivate IE, sfc /scannow (3th issue), Uninstalling IE etc..all failed.

Finally I found a tool (tweaking.com - Windows Repair All in one) that solved the First issue.

Now there are still two more problems - Windows Update IE11 fails with code 9C48, and the `sfc /scannow` fails at 14%

If you search the web for the error 9C48, there are many other people with the exact same issue, but I am unable to apply the proposed solutions to my case and after a little investigation I have found myself in this strange situation:

From IE -> About Internet Explorer -> Version Installed 11.0.9600.17**358**

From the binary iexplorer.exe -> Properties -> Details Tab -> Version Installed 11.0.9600.17**280**

From Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> View Installed Update -> I can see only Windows Internet Explore **10** ...
So i'm little bit confused.

For the `sfc /scannow` fail, I have no idea. Here's the CBS.log

```
POQ 18 ends.
2014-10-23 16:35:12, Info                  CSI    00000054 [SR] Verify complete
2014-10-23 16:35:12, Info                  CSI    00000055 [SR] Verifying 100 (0x0000000000000064) components
2014-10-23 16:35:12, Info                  CSI    00000056 [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2014-10-23 16:35:13, Info                  CSI    00000057 Repair results created:
POQ 19 starts:

POQ 19 ends.
2014-10-23 16:35:13, Info                  CSI    00000058 [SR] Verify complete
2014-10-23 16:35:14, Info                  CSI    00000059 [SR] Verifying 100 (0x0000000000000064) components
2014-10-23 16:35:14, Info                  CSI    0000005a [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2014-10-23 16:35:15, Info                  CSI    0000005b [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:20{10}]"pcasvc.dll" of Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience-Program-Compatibility-Assistant, Version = 6.1.7601.18526, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-10-23 16:35:15, Info                  CSI    0000005c [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:30{15}]"setupcompat.dll" of Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience-Upgrade-Compat-Telemetry, Version = 6.1.7601.18635, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-10-23 16:35:15, Info                  CSI    0000005d [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:42{21}]"DVDPlaybackCompat.dll" of Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience-Upgrade-Compat-Telemetry, Version = 6.1.7601.18635, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-10-23 16:35:15, Info                  CSI    0000005e [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:28{14}]"hwcompat64.txt" of Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience-Upgrade-Compat-Telemetry, Version = 6.1.7601.18635, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-10-23 16:35:15, Info                  CSI    0000005f [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:28{14}]"hwcompat32.txt" of Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience-Upgrade-Compat-Telemetry, Version = 6.1.7601.18635, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-10-23 16:35:15, Info                  CSI    00000060 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:36{18}]"SBCompatPlugin.dll" of Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience-Upgrade-Compat-Telemetry, Version = 6.1.7601.18635, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-10-23 16:35:15, Info                  CSI    00000061 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:30{15}]"TouchCompat.dll" of Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience-Upgrade-Compat-Telemetry, Version = 6.1.7601.18635, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-10-23 16:35:15, Info                  CSI    00000062 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:34{17}]"wicainventory.exe" of Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience-Upgrade-Compat-Telemetry, Version = 6.1.7601.18635, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-10-23 16:35:15, Info                  CSI    00000063 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:20{10}]"DevInv.dll" of Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience-Upgrade-Compat-Telemetry, Version = 6.1.7601.18635, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-10-23 16:35:15, Info                  CSI    00000064 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:22{11}]"sdbapiu.dll" of Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience-Upgrade-Compat-Telemetry, Version = 6.1.7601.18635, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-10-23 16:35:15, Info                  CSI    00000065 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:24{12}]"cosquery.dll" of Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience-Upgrade-Compat-Telemetry, Version = 6.1.7601.18635, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-10-23 16:35:15, Info                  CSI    00000066 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:38{19}]"compatResources.dll" of Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience-Upgrade-Compat-Telemetry, Version = 6.1.7601.18635, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-10-23 16:35:15, Info                  CSI    00000067 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:42{21}]"MediaCenterCompat.dll" of Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience-Upgrade-Compat-Telemetry, Version = 6.1.7601.18635, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-10-23 16:35:15, Info                  CSI    00000068 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:32{16}]"compatplugin.dll" of Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience-Upgrade-Compat-Telemetry, Version = 6.1.7601.18635, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-10-23 16:35:15, Info                  CSI    00000069 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:34{17}]"QueryAppBlock.exe" of Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience-Upgrade-Compat-Telemetry, Version = 6.1.7601.18635, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-10-23 16:35:15, Info                  CSI    0000006a [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:28{14}]"compatctrl.dll" of Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience-Upgrade-Compat-Telemetry, Version = 6.1.7601.18635, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-10-23 16:35:15, Info                  CSI    0000006b [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:22{11}]"wdscore.dll" of Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience-Upgrade-Compat-Telemetry, Version = 6.1.7601.18635, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-10-23 16:35:15, Info                  CSI    0000006c [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:30{15}]"hwexclude32.txt" of Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience-Upgrade-Compat-Telemetry, Version = 6.1.7601.18635, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-10-23 16:35:15, Info                  CSI    0000006d [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:30{15}]"hwexclude64.txt" of Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience-Upgrade-Compat-Telemetry, Version = 6.1.7601.18635, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-10-23 16:35:15, Info                  CSI    0000006e [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:28{14}]"generaltel.dll" of Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience-Upgrade-Compat-Telemetry, Version = 6.1.7601.18635, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-10-23 16:35:15, Info                  CSI    0000006f [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:18{9}]"aeinv.dll" of Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience-Upgrade-Compat-Telemetry, Version = 6.1.7601.18635, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-10-23 16:35:15, Info                  CSI    00000070 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:16{8}]"wica.dll" of Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience-Upgrade-Compat-Telemetry, Version = 6.1.7601.18635, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-10-23 16:35:15, Info                  CSI    00000071 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:40{20}]"GadgetCompliance.dll" of Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience-Upgrade-Compat-Telemetry, Version = 6.1.7601.18635, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-10-23 16:35:15, Info                  CSI    00000072 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:26{13}]"sysmain64.sdb" of Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience-Telemetry-SDBs, Version = 6.1.7601.18635, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-10-23 16:35:15, Info                  CSI    00000073 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:26{13}]"sysmain32.sdb" of Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience-Telemetry-SDBs, Version = 6.1.7601.18635, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-10-23 16:35:15, Info                  CSI    00000074 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:40{20}]"sysmain32runtime.sdb" of Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience-Telemetry-SDBs, Version = 6.1.7601.18635, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-10-23 16:35:15, Info                  CSI    00000075 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:26{13}]"drvmain64.sdb" of Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience-Telemetry-SDBs, Version = 6.1.7601.18635, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-10-23 16:35:15, Info                  CSI    00000076 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:26{13}]"drvmain32.sdb" of Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience-Telemetry-SDBs, Version = 6.1.7601.18635, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-10-23 16:35:15, Info                  CSI    00000077 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:40{20}]"sysmain64runtime.sdb" of Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience-Telemetry-SDBs, Version = 6.1.7601.18635, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-10-23 16:35:15, Info                  CSI    00000078 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:26{13}]"sysmain64.sdb" of Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience-Telemetry-SDBs, Version = 6.1.7601.18635, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-10-23 16:35:15, Info                  CSI    00000079 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:26{13}]"sysmain32.sdb" of Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience-Telemetry-SDBs, Version = 6.1.7601.18635, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-10-23 16:35:15, Info                  CSI    0000007a [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:40{20}]"sysmain32runtime.sdb" of Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience-Telemetry-SDBs, Version = 6.1.7601.18635, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-10-23 16:35:15, Info                  CSI    0000007b [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:26{13}]"drvmain64.sdb" of Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience-Telemetry-SDBs, Version = 6.1.7601.18635, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-10-23 16:35:15, Info                  CSI    0000007c [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:26{13}]"drvmain32.sdb" of Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience-Telemetry-SDBs, Version = 6.1.7601.18635, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-10-23 16:35:15, Info                  CSI    0000007d [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:40{20}]"sysmain64runtime.sdb" of Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience-Telemetry-SDBs, Version = 6.1.7601.18635, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-10-23 16:35:15, Error                 CSI    0000007e (F) STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND #1340953# from Windows::Rtl::SystemImplementation::DirectFileSystemProvider::SysCreateFile(flags = (AllowSharingViolation), handle = {provider=NULL, handle=0}, da = (SYNCHRONIZE|FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES), oa = @0xedcb40->OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES {s:48; rd:NULL; on:[122]"\??\C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-a..ence-telemetry-sdbs_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.18635_none_66352fe660ac93de"; a:(OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE)}, iosb = @0xedcb20, as = (null), fa = 0, sa = (FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE|FILE_SHARE_DELETE), cd = FILE_OPEN, co = (FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT|0x00004000), eab = NULL, eal = 0, disp = Invalid)
[gle=0xd0000034]
2014-10-23 16:35:15, Error                 CSI    0000007f@2014/10/23:14:35:15.856 (F) d:\win7sp1_gdr\base\wcp\sil\merged\ntu\ntsystem.cpp(2057): Error STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND originated in function Windows::Rtl::SystemImplementation::DirectFileSystemProvider::SysCreateFile expression: (null)
[gle=0x80004005]
2014-10-23 16:35:17, Error                 CSI    00000080 (F) STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND #1340952# from Windows::Rtl::SystemImplementation::CDirectory::OpenExistingDirectory(...)[gle=0xd0000034]
2014-10-23 16:35:17, Error                 CSI    00000081 (F) STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND #1340951# from Windows::Rtl::SystemImplementation::CDirectory_IRtlDirectoryTearoff::OpenExistingDirectory(flags = 0, da = (SYNCHRONIZE), oa = @0xedd438->SIL_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES {s:40; on:"amd64_microsoft-windows-a..ence-telemetry-sdbs_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.18635_none_66352fe660ac93de"; a:(OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE)}, sa = (FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE|FILE_SHARE_DELETE), oo = (FILE_DIRECTORY_FILE|FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT|FILE_OPEN_FOR_BACKUP_INTENT), dir = NULL, disp = Invalid)
[gle=0xd0000034]
2014-10-23 16:35:17, Error                 CSI    00000082 (F) STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND #1340947# from CFileInstaller::DoComponentOperation(...)[gle=0xd0000034]
2014-10-23 16:35:17, Error                 CSI    00000083 (F) STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND #1340946# from PrimitiveInstaller::CCoordinator::RepairComponent(Component = Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience-Telemetry-SDBs, Version = 6.1.7601.18635, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral)[gle=0xd0000034]
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You had disk/file-system corruption, it corrupted both the active system files and their source that the repairs are pulled from by SFC (`%windir%\WinSxS`).

So first, test your disks thoroughly to ensure they are OK.

Then, for each "file is missing" error you will need to identify the file needed and get a good copy of it from someplace else (like another working Windows install), and then insert it into your system.

How to do this is explained in the "For more information" section of MS KB Article #929833 - [Use the System File Checker tool to repair missing or corrupted system files](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833)

Or just give up now and reinstall (after testing your disks thoroughly) as, in the end, it's probably quicker and is your best bet at ensuring you end up with a stable OS.